# Hot tracking list item selection in a combo box

Tags: winapi, combobox, mfc

I have a combo box and I need to intercept the changement of the selection while the user changes the selection by just hovering with the mouse *without* clicking. This is for displaying complementary information about the item the user is hovering over.

`CBN_SELCHANGE` won't do the job, because this message gets fired only when the user has *actually* changed the selection by clicking on one of the combo box items or when the up/down keys are pressed.

Apparently no message is fired while the user is just hovering over the the combobox.

**Illustration**

E.g: I need to know when the user moves the mouse from the entry `2` to the entry `33`.

[image]

Comment: I cannot get my plain win32 combobox to hot track with the mouse. How are you managing it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I can't. That's actually the question:. How to hot track.

Comment: So you want to modify the behaviour of the standard combo box so that it hot tracks? That's a really bad idea in terms of UX.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I actually want to display some complementary information about the item the user is hovering on.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I wasn't aware that this was called "hot tracking". By doing some research using the term "hot tracking", I've found [this article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14255/ComboBox-firing-events-when-hovering-on-the-dropdo) which does what I want. It's for C#, and not C or C++, but I can probably use the information provided there.

Comment: Displaying info for hot track is fine. Changing the selection is probably not.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's definitely for displaying information and in no way for actually changing tge selection. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The question is quite misleading then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is c++ subclass based on [c# article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14255/ComboBox-firing-events-when-hovering-on-the-dropdo) which you mentioned:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ComboProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, 
    LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubClass, DWORD_PTR)
{
    if (msg == WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX)
    {
        COMBOBOXINFO ci = { sizeof(COMBOBOXINFO) };
        GetComboBoxInfo(hwnd, &ci);
        if (HWND(lParam) == ci.hwndList)
        {
            int pos = SendMessage(ci.hwndList, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
            OutputDebugStringA(std::to_string(pos).c_str());
            OutputDebugStringA("\n");
        }
    }

    if (msg == WM_NCDESTROY)
    {
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, ComboProc, uIdSubClass);
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

...
SetWindowSubclass(hComboBox, ComboProc, 0, 0);
```

This was tested on Windows 10.

This can only report the hover selection in drop down list, it can't change the selection.