# What does it mean for a ComboBox to be "hot"?

Tags: winforms, combobox

ComboBoxes have a [ComboBoxState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.comboboxstate(v=vs.110).aspx), which can be *Normal*, *Disabled*, *Pressed*, or *Hot*.

The first three seem obvious, but what is "Hot"?

Comment: [VisualStyleElement.ComboBox.DropDownButton.Hot Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.combobox.dropdownbutton.hot(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You may follow this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36287605/hot-tracking-list-item-selection-in-a-combo-box Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: But what is this "hot state"? What does it look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's when the mouse is over the control:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
  int top = 16;
  foreach (ComboBoxState cbs in new ComboBoxState[] { ComboBoxState.Normal,
                                                      ComboBoxState.Disabled,
                                                      ComboBoxState.Pressed,
                                                      ComboBoxState.Hot}) {
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(16, top, 84, 21);
    ComboBoxRenderer.DrawTextBox(e.Graphics, r, cbs);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, cbs.ToString(), this.Font, r, Color.Black);
    ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton(e.Graphics, 
                                        new Rectangle(16 + 84, top, 21, 21), cbs);
    top += 23;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see. Perfect. Thank you!